# MYSQL - UPDATE first char of string in COLUMN

Tags: mysql

I would like to update the first char of a column in MYSQL

```
WHERE the format of the string is LIKE '1-%'
```

change the first char to '0'.

I have created this example and think I am on the right tracks...

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
   has_roundel = REPLACE(has_roundel, SUBSTRING(has_roundel, 0, 1),'0')
WHERE
   has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Comment: ok so what is the problem? Error?

Comment: It sounds as though you may be trying to manipulate badly denormalised data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL SUBSTRING isnt starting from 0.

You can use:

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
   has_roundel = REPLACE(has_roundel, SUBSTRING(has_roundel, 1, 1),'0')
WHERE
   has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Or:

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
   has_roundel = REPLACE(has_roundel, SUBSTRING(has_roundel, 1),'0')
WHERE
   has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
update products
set
    has_roundel = concat('0', substring(has_roundel, 2))
where
    has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
   has_roundel = REPLACE(has_roundel, LEFT(has_roundel,1),'0')
WHERE
   has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Or:

```
 UPDATE products 
    SET 
       has_roundel = Concat('0',SUBSTR(data, 2))
    WHERE
       has_roundel like '1-%';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make use of `CONCAT`

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
   has_roundel = CONCAT('0-', substring(has_roundel, 3))
WHERE
   has_roundel like '1-%';
```